# Webpack reports error: __diranme is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dirname

I'm new to NodeJS and webpack.

I'm following a tutorial on webpack and when have to create
webpack.config.js and run `webpack -c webpack.config.js` it returns:

```
webpack -c webpack.config.js

/home/arma/bin/nodejs/webpack.config.js:15
        root: path.join(__diranme, './src'),
                        ^
ReferenceError: __diranme is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arma/bin/nodejs/webpack.config.js:15:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:80:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:39:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        './src/index.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'output.js',
        publicPath: 'assets',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['','.js'],
        root: path.join(__diranme, './src'),
    }
};
```

My system Fedora 23:

```
Linux x-wing 4.4.5-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 10 17:54:44 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

NodeJS version:

```
v0.10.42
```

Comment: I think this question needs to be deleted - useful title, but resolution isn't helpful for this error generally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename to __dirname. You have a typo in the resolve section. Also in your post title :-)

Comment: what a idiot am i! Thank you :)
but now i got 
ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./src/index.js in __dirname
 @ multi main

Comment: Please flag typo questions as off-topic.

Comment: What the better way to flag questions as off-topic?